Solid Queue 0.8.2 with sql schema format
From my understanding, solid cache 0.8.2 replaces migrations with a schema to be loaded (available at /db/queue_schema.rb after running bin/rails solid_queue:install).
In my Rails app, I use the sql schema format and am unsure how to load the queue schema.
My database.yml file looks like
development:
  primary: &primary_development
    <<: *default
    database: appa_development
  queue:
    <<: *primary_development
    database: appa_development_queue
    migrations_paths: db/queue_migrate

And when I run bin/rails db:schema:load:queue SCHEMA_FORMAT="ruby" I get
bin/rails aborted!
TypeError: Invalid type for configuration. Expected Symbol, String, or Hash. Got nil (TypeError)

        raise TypeError, "Invalid type for configuration. Expected Symbol, String, or Hash. Got #{config.inspect}"
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load:queue => db:test:purge:queue

I don't have defined the queue database for the test environment since I don't plan to use it. So, how can I load the content of ueue_schema.rb only on appa_development_queue?


Create the db/queue_migrations directory
Create a new migration called "solid_queue_setup" and move it from db/migrations to db/queue_migrations
Edit it and include the contents of the db/queue_schema.rb in the "change" method
Remove db/queue_schema.rb
Run "rake db:setup:queue"

At this point, you should have your queue_structure.sql file.

Thanks. I upgraded to SolidQueue 1.1.0.
